# Why does my computer's audio shut off when I connect a VGA/DVI-I cable?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

i'm trying to do dual monitors with an 1920X1080 LG monitor which works just fine and has every since i set it up with my computer, and a Vizio 1024X768 monitor. I had to get a VGA cable and a VGA DVI-D conversion box in order for it to work with my NVIDIA GTX 1060 graphics card.

When i got the cables in the mail and hooked it up today, the secondary display worked fine at first, but everytime i connect the vga and vga/dvi-d, it immediately cuts off my sound for both monitors! Why does it do this?

Comment: How are the speakers connected? Does your OS show a mute icon?

Comment: no it doesn't, and speaker just comes through the monitor, the monitor is basically just a standard 36" television

Comment: So how is the sound transferred to the TV? HDMI?

Comment: the sound doesn't get transferred, it comes out of the television because most televisions have their own speakers. The way i fixed my dilemma is i figured out how to turn on the onboard sound on the motherboard, now there aren't any issues, but I'm still curious as to why plugging a DVI-D/VGA cable into my graphics card shuts off the sound for both monitors.

Comment: Let me try to explain. Your TV is connected to your pc. It displays an image and plays the pc's audio through its speakers. So how is the TV connected to the pc so that it's able to do this?

Comment: well, there a pin in the motherboard that says "audio", otherwise i just don't know what's going on, so I can't explain that to you.